# Size of the image in carousel change when moved to next slide

Tags: html, jquery, css, sharepoint

I am trying to display a list in carousel format in Sharepoint classic. Items are displayed in carousel format dynamically but when the next/prev button is triggered the size of the images change.

When I use static data it's working well. The carousel is a slideshow for cycling through a series of content, built with CSS 3D transforms and a bit of JavaScript. It works with a series of images, text, or custom markup. It also includes support for previous/next controls and indicators

```js
function redirect(testss) {
  alert(testss);
  localStorage.setItem("annouce", testss);
  location.href = 'Detail_annoucement.aspx';
}

function carouseltest() {
  var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Announce')/items?$orderby=Modified desc&$top=12";
  console.log("url", requestUri);
  $.ajax({
    url: requestUri,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
      "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    },
    success: carouselSuccess,
    error: onError
  });
}

function carouselSuccess(data) {
  var Items = data.d.results;
  var htmlcontent = ' ';
  var newhtml = '';
  
  $(document).ready(function() {
    debugger;
    for (let j = 0; j < Items.length; j++) {
      $('<div class="carousel-item"><a href="javascript:redirect(' + Items[j].Id + ')" ><img src="' + Items[j].Image.Url + '" style="width:100%; height: 500px;border-radius: 10px;"></a> <div class="carousel-caption" style="left: 5%;width:300px;height: 80px;margin-top: 15px;text-align: left;padding:5px;margin-bottom:20px;"><h3> ' + Items[j].Title + '</h3> <p> ' + Items[j].Description + '</p> </div> </div>').appendTo('.carousel-inner');
      $('<li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="' + j + '">  </li>').appendTo('.carousel-indicators')
    }

    $('.carousel-item').first().addClass('active');
    $('.carousel-indicators > li').first().addClass('active');
    $('#carousel').carousel({});
  });
}

function onError(error) {
  alert(Error);
}

setTimeout(function() {
  carouseltest();
}, 2500);
```

```css
.carousel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 470px;
  min-height: 500px
}

.carousel-control.left,
.carousel-control.right {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.carousel-inner {
  height: 470px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 500px
}

.carousel-indicators>li {
  flex: start;
  background-color: white;
}

.carousel-indicators {}

.carousel-indicators .active {
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: blue;
}

.carousel-control-prev {
  height: 10%;
  width: 10%;
  margin-top: 20%;
  color: white;
}

.carousel-control-next {
  height: 10%;
  width: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-top: 20%;
  color: red;
}

.glyphicon {
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-top: 150%;
  color: white;
}

.carousel-control {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  top: 300px;
}


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" interval="false">
  <div class="carousel-inner"></div>
  <ol class="carousel-indicators"></ol>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Test your script while not find the issue you mentioned.

Try to use developer tool to compare the CSS difference.

```
<style type="text/css">
        .carousel {
            width: 100%;
            height: 470px;
            min-height: 500px
        }

        .carousel-control.left,
        .carousel-control.right {
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .carousel-inner {
            height: 470px;
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 500px
        }

        .carousel-indicators > li {
            flex: start;
            background-color: white;
        }

        .carousel-indicators {
        }

            .carousel-indicators .active {
                width: 13px;
                height: 13px;
                justify-content: flex-start;
                background-color: blue;
            }

        .carousel-control-prev {
            height: 10%;
            width: 10%;
            margin-top: 20%;
            color: white;
        }

        .carousel-control-next {
            height: 10%;
            width: 10%;
            margin-right: 10%;
            margin-top: 20%;
            color: red;
        }

        .glyphicon {
            font-size: 35px;
            margin-top: 150%;
            color: white;
        }

        .carousel-control {
            position: absolute;
            color: white;
            top: 300px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            carouseltest();
        })
        function redirect(testss) {
            alert(testss);
            localStorage.setItem("annouce", testss);
            location.href = 'Detail_annoucement.aspx';
        }

        function carouseltest() {
            var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Announce')/items?$orderby=Modified desc&$top=12";
            console.log("url", requestUri);
            $.ajax({
                url: requestUri,
                type: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
                },
                success: carouselSuccess,
                error: onError
            });
        }

        function carouselSuccess(data) {
            var Items = data.d.results;
            var htmlcontent = ' ';
            var newhtml = '';

            //$(document).ready(function () {
            //    debugger;
            for (let j = 0; j < Items.length; j++) {
                $('<div class="carousel-item"><a href="javascript:redirect(' + Items[j].Id + ')" ><img src="' + Items[j].Image.Url + '" style="width:100%; height: 500px;border-radius: 10px;"></a> <div class="carousel-caption" style="left: 5%;width:300px;height: 80px;margin-top: 15px;text-align: left;padding:5px;margin-bottom:20px;"><h3> ' + Items[j].Title + '</h3> <p> ' + Items[j].Description + '</p> </div> </div>').appendTo('.carousel-inner');
                $('<li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="' + j + '">  </li>').appendTo('.carousel-indicators')
            }

            $('.carousel-item').first().addClass('active');
            $('.carousel-indicators > li').first().addClass('active');
            $('#carousel').carousel({});
            //});
        }

        function onError(error) {
            alert(Error);
        }

        setTimeout(function () {
            carouseltest();
        }, 2500);
    </script>

    <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" interval="false">
        <div class="carousel-inner"></div>
        <ol class="carousel-indicators"></ol>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

[image]

[image]